# CSS website layers structure

Tags: css, structure, positioning

I need help with website layers structure, i want to look like this picture [`website-example`](http://oi61.tinypic.com/vncw0p.jpg) but i'm confused about the `display:` function in CSS, someone explain me what should i do ? Here is the code i have so far: [`JSFIDDLE`](https://jsfiddle.net/o44rh3m5/)

When ill put `display: table-cell` in the `.news` class all html elements are messed up, and my expectations is to start new line after the `news` box so the `tickets` to come under the `news` box, someone explain me what should i do to fix this problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll have to read up on the different CSS properties and how they interact.

Comment: Can you show me in the code bellow how can i display inline the elements and after the `news` box the `ticket` box to go under ?

Comment: Anyone who can help me please ?